# Check in bash if I am in a Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: linux, bash, google-compute-engine

I would like to check in a bash script whether I am in a Google Compute Engine instance or in my Linux laptop. How can I differentiate them?

Comment: If you want to make sure that your terminal is/isn't runnin on your Linux laptop, why not check if the hostname matches to your laptop's? There might be reasons why you wouldn't wanna go that way, but your explanation is sparse.

Comment: This script is shared between multiple developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Detect if a VM is running in Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/detect-compute-engine) at GCE documentation:

```
$ curl metadata.google.internal -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Metadata-Flavor: Google
Content-Type: application/text
Date: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 01:27:16 GMT
Server: Metadata Server for VM
Content-Length: 22
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

0.1/
computeMetadata/
```

You can use the internal IP (169.254.169.254) for the metadata server instead.

The documentation (link above) also provides an alternative that uses an operating system tool:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name | grep "Google Compute Engine"
case $? in
(0) echo On a GCE instance;;
(*) echo Not a GCE instance;;
esac
```

or

```
$ dmesg | grep -q "BIOS Google"
case $? in
(0) echo On a GCE instance;;
(*) echo Not a GCE instance;;
esac
```

Checking for relevant strings as "google", "virt" or "kvm" in dmesg output can provide hints too.